# Google place automplete Angular, get text if not found results

Tags: javascript, angular, events, maps

I am building an autocomplete component for address search with google maps service, for which I am using Angular 9. My component works, but I NEED TO CAPTURE THE VALUE OF THE INPUT WHEN THERE ARE NO SEARCHES AVAILABLE USING THE BLUR EVENT OR WHEN THE INPUT LOSE FOCUS.

Currently the component detects when I select an address, but I need to make it also detect the text I type when it does not find anything.

my html:

```
 <input #search class="form-control" [formControl]="myAddress" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
```

My ts:

```
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onSelectAddress = new EventEmitter<CustomAddressModel>();

  myAddress = new FormControl('');
  selectedAddress: PlaceResult;

  @ViewChild('search')
  searchElementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private _mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this._mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {

      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement);
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {

          this.selectedAddress = autocomplete.getPlace();

          if (!this.selectedAddress.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          const result = {
              lat: this.selectedAddress.geometry.location.lat(),
              long:  this.selectedAddress.geometry.location.lng(),
              strAddress:  this.selectedAddress.formatted_address
          } as CustomAddressModel;

          this.onSelectAddress.emit(result);

        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually you need to subscribe to the value changes of the input control.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formchanges();
  }


  formchanges()
  {
     this.yourform.controls['myAddress'].valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      finalize(() => {
        
      })).subscribe(x => {
      var address = safeTrim(this.yourform.get('myAddress').value);

          this.getAddress(address);
        }
      });
  }
  
  getAddress()
  {
     //your call to the google maps api goes here 
  }
```

I am not sure , I was able to answer to your question or not.

Comment: Perfect! works for me, thanks!